# Savon seems to be reading only the first port of a multi port soap service

Tags: ruby, xml, savon

I am using Savon with the following WSDL

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:v2bind="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsrp:v2:bind" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsrp:v2:wsdl">
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsrp:v2:bind" location="http://localhost:8080/wsrp-portlet/wsdl/wsrp-2.0-bindings.wsdl"/>
<wsdl:service name="WSRP_v2_Service">
    <wsdl:port binding="v2bind:WSRP_v2_Markup_Binding_SOAP" name="WSRP_v2_Markup_Service">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/wsrp-portlet/services/WSRP_v2_Markup_Service?wsrpProducerUuid=48322cfd-c68b-4053-b9b4-aff1644d6e1e"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port binding="v2bind:WSRP_v2_ServiceDescription_Binding_SOAP" name="WSRP_v2_ServiceDescription_Service">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/wsrp-portlet/services/WSRP_v2_ServiceDescription_Service?wsrpProducerUuid=48322cfd-c68b-4053-b9b4-aff1644d6e1e"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port binding="v2bind:WSRP_v2_Registration_Binding_SOAP" name="WSRP_v2_Registration_Service">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/wsrp-portlet/services/WSRP_v2_Registration_Service?wsrpProducerUuid=48322cfd-c68b-4053-b9b4-aff1644d6e1e"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port binding="v2bind:WSRP_v2_PortletManagement_Binding_SOAP" name="WSRP_v2_PortletManagement_Service">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/wsrp-portlet/services/WSRP_v2_PortletManagement_Service?wsrpProducerUuid=48322cfd-c68b-4053-b9b4-aff1644d6e1e"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

When I inspect,

```
savon.wsdl.endpoint
```

I only get,

```
#<URI::HTTP:0x00000101eea398 URL:http://localhost:8080/wsrp-portlet/services/WSRP_v2_Markup_Service?wsrpProducerUuid=48322cfd-c68b-4053-b9b4-aff1644d6e1e>
```

Can savon handle a wsdl with multiple port definitions? If not any suggestions on a ruby alternative that does support it?

Answer (score 1):

I have been seeing the same thing with Savon.  I can manually change the endpoint by setting the endpoint explicitly with

```
Savon.client do
  wsdl.endpoint = "http://service.example.com"
end
```